# How to write a PPX rewriter generating lenses for records?

Tags: ocaml, metaprogramming

I am writing a PPX rewriter to ease the definition of [Lenses](https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-lens).  Let me recall for the casual reader what *lenses* are.

### About lenses

A *lens* associated with a field of a record is a pair of functions allowing to extract the record and update it. Here is an example:

```
module Lens =
struct
  type ('a, 'b) t = {
    get : 'a -> 'b;
    set : 'b -> 'a -> 'a
  }
end

type car = {
  vendor: string;
  make: string;
  mileage: int;
}

let vendor_lens = {
  Lens.get = (fun x -> x.vendor);
  Lens.set = (fun v x -> { x with vendor = v })
}
```

The `vendor_lens` allows us to get the value of the field `vendor` in our `car` and to update it – which means returning a fresh copy of the `car` differing from the original only by the value of the `vendor` car.  This might at first sound very *banal* but it is not: since lenses are essentially functions, they can be composed and the [Lenses](https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-lens) module is filled with useful functions.  The ability to compose accessors is crucial in complex code bases, as it eases the decoupling by abstracting the path from a computation context to a deeply nested record.  I also recently refactored my [Getopts](https://github.com/michipili/getopts) and [configuration file parser](https://github.com/michipili/configuration) to adopt a functional interface, which makes lenses even more relevant – at least for me.

### Generating lenses

The definition of `vendor_lens` above is nothing more than [boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) and there is really no reason one could not take advantage of PPX-rewriters to let us simply write

```
type car = {
  vendor: string;
  make: string;
  mileage: int;
} [@@with_lenses]
```

and see automagically definition of the lenses we need to work with our car.¹

I decided to tackle the problem and could produce:

1. a predicate `is_record : Parsetree.structure_item -> bool` recognising type record definitions.
2. a function `label_declarations : Parsetree.structure_item -> string list` maybe returning the list of record declarations for a record definition – *yes, we could smash 1 and 2 together using an option*.
3. a function `lens_expr : string ->  Parsetree.structure_item` generating the lens definition for a given field declaration. Unfortunately I discovered [ppx_metaquot](https://github.com/alainfrisch/ppx_tools#ppx_metaquot) by Alain Frisch after I wrote this function.

It seems to me I have here the essential parts of the PPX-rewriter I want to write. Still, how can I combine them together?

---

¹ While searching for a PPX-rewriter for lenses, I stumbled on not less than five blogs or READMEs involving the very same `car` structure. Recycling this example here is a vile attempt to look like a full-time member of the selective club of lens-equipped car drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final goal of your PPX project is to build a mapper of type `Ast_mapper.mapper`.

`mapper` is a large record type and carries mapper functions for the `Parsetree` data types, for example,

```
type mapper = { 
  ...
  structure : mapper -> structure -> structure;
  signature : mapper -> signature -> signature;
  ...
}
```

There is a default mapper `Ast_mapper.default_mapper` and this is the starting point of your mapper: you can inherit it and override some of record members for your use. For your lens project, you have to implement `structure` and `signature`:

```
let extend super =
  let structure self str = ... in
  let signature self str = ... in
  { super with structure; signature }

let mapper = extend default_mapper
```

Your function `structure` should scan the structure items and add an appropriate value definition for each record type declaration. `signature` should do the same thing but add signatures of lens functions:

```
let structure self str = List.concat (List.map (fun sitem -> match sitem.pstr_desc with
  | Pstr_type tds when tds_with_lenses sitem ->
      sitem :: sitems_for_your_lens_functions
  | _ -> [sitem]) str)
in  
let signature self str = List.concat (List.map (fun sgitem -> match sgiitem.psig_desc with
  | Psig_type tds when tds_with_lenses sitem ->
      sgitem :: sgitems_for_your_lens_functions
  | _ -> [sgitem]) str)
in
```

`super` and `self` are as same as those of OO: `super` is the original mapper your are extending and `self` is the result of extension. (Actually for the very first version of `Ast_mapper` used a class instead of the record type. If you prefer OO style, you can use `Ast_mapper_class` of ppx_tools package, which provides the same in OO interface.)  In anyway.. I guess in your case, there is no need to use `self` or `super` arguments.

Once you finish your own mapper then give it `Ast_mapper.apply` to run the mapper against the input:

```
let () =
  let infile = .. in
  let outfile = .. in
  Ast_mapper.apply ~source:infile ~target:outfile mapper
```

More or less, all the PPX rewriter implementations are like the above. Checking several small PPX implementations surely helps your understanding.

Comment: Thanks to your help I could finish the mini-project. My understanding is that AST mappers are continuation-style recursive functions, right?  For the program entry point I used `let () = Ast_mapper.run_main (fun _ -> lens_extender default_mapper)`.  Are you aware of tools using `ppx_tools.metaquot` which I could study to get started with metaquot? Currently I explicitly generate a Parsetree structure with a big Parsetree blob, it is not pretty!

Comment: We did an NYC OCaml Meetup on ppx. It's not much, but the code reviewed is [here](https://github.com/agarwal/ppx_basic_demo).

Comment: Yes, `Ast_mapper.run_main` is an easier entry point.  Personally I use `apply` since it is more general.  `ppx_tools.metaquot` is great to reduce your work complexity.